# Which bolts am I missing in Ratchet and Clank (2016)?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-2016

My game is showing I've collected all the bolts on each planet, but I've only got 26, what am I missing?

When I get in my ship to travel each place shows 2/2 or 3/3 for example - none missing, but obviously I am missing 2 somewhere.

What say the experts?

Answer (score 3):

It just sounds like you are not on the last planet. You should have 12 planets and conveniently enough the last planet has 2 bolts on it.

- Veldin - 1
- Novalis - 0
- Kerwan - 2
- Aridia - 3
- Nebula G34 - 1
- Rilgar - 3
- Gaspar - 4
- Batalia - 3
- Pokitaru - 3
- Quartu - 3
- Kalebo III - 3
- Deplanetizer - 2